# View of the resource tab in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, tabs, resources

I tried adding a resource to a project in visual studio 2015 community.

However the resource tab is blank. I know its supposed to look like the image below, but I don't have anything on the left. No application or settings. What went wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np54W.png)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to double click the properties folder in the Solution Explorer,

If you open the resources.resx folder Directly you wont see the toolbar on the left.

alternatively you can look at the properties tab at the bottom of the project Menu